# Converting random operator add, mul or sub into a string + * -

Tags: python

I am sorry but I am a newbie here & to python and I could not find an answer in other questions.

What I am trying to do is convert the random maths operator to a string so I can use it within a print statement question. This is what I have done, which I know is wrong, but I wanted you to see my logic.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
while not exitProgram:
    for count in range(10):
        print ("Question ", (count+1),":")
        integer1 = random.randint(0,10)
        print (integer1) #This is used for testing
        integer2 = random.randint(0,10)
        print (integer2)#Again used for testing
        ops = add,sub,mul
        op = random.choice(ops)
        print (op) #testing
        correctAnswer = op(integer1, integer2)
        print (correctAnswer)
        opPrint = ""
        if op == <built-in function sub>:
            opPrint = "-"
            print (opPrint)
        if op == "<built-in function mul>":
            opPrint = "*"
            print (opPrint)
        if op == "<built-in function add>":
            opPrint = "+"
            print (opPrint)

        print ("What is " ,integer1, opPrint, integer2)
        answer = int(input("Please enter your answer\n"))
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense; comparing an object to a string like is never going to work (except to see whether it's literally that string). Consider putting your operator functions in a dictionary `{'+': add, ...}`, that will make your life much easier.

Comment: I read that as *"comparing an object to a string is like never going to work"* and was going cross-eyed trying to see *why*!

Comment: @Borodin missing *"that"*, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random                                                    

def add(int1, int2):                                             
    return int1+int2                                             
def sub(int1, int2):                                             
    return int1-int2                                             
def mul(int1, int2):                                             
    return int1*int2                                             

exitProgram = False                                              
while not exitProgram:                                           
    for count in range(10):                                      
        print("Question "+str(count+1)+":")                      
        integer1 = random.randint(0,10)                          
        integer2 = random.randint(0,10)                          
        ops = add,sub,mul                                        
        op = random.choice(ops)                                  
        correctAnswer = op(integer1, integer2)                   
        opPrint = ""                                             
        if op == sub:                                            
            opPrint = "-"                                        
        if op == mul:                                            
            opPrint = "*"                                        
        if op == add:                                            
            opPrint = "+"                                        

        print ("What is "+str(integer1)+opPrint+str(integer2))   
        answer = int(input("Please enter your answer\n"))
```

Comment: @RH84, does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module, which provides access to the standard operators as a set of functions. Here, you want `operator.__add__`, `operator.__sub__`, and `operator.__mul__`.

Rather then an `if` / `elif` / `else` chain, it is cleaner to use a *dictionary* to map between a code reference and a string.

I would write your program like this

```
import random
from operator import __add__, __sub__, __mul__

ops = __add__, __sub__, __mul__

symbols = {
    __add__: '+',
    __sub__: '-',
    __mul__: '*',
}

score = 0

for count in range(10):

    p1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    p2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    op = random.choice(ops)

    sum_text = '%d %s %d' % (p1, symbols[op], p2)

    print('\nQuestion %d: what is %s?' % (count + 1, sum_text))
    answer = int(input('Please enter your answer: '))

    correct_answer = op(p1, p2)

    if answer == correct_answer:
        print('Correct!')
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Sorry, that's wrong")
        print('The correct answer is %d' % correct_answer)

print('You scored a total of %d out of %d' % (score, 10))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
def add(i1,i2):
    return i1+i2
def sub(i1,i2):
    return i1-i2
def mul(i1,i2):  
    return i1*i2
exitProgram=True

while exitProgram:

    for count in range(10):

        print ("Question ", (count+1),":")
        integer1 = random.randint(0,10)
        print ("test",integer1) #This is used for testing
        integer2 = random.randint(0,10)
        print ("again testing",integer2)#Again used for testing
        ops = add,sub,mul
        op = random.choice(ops)
        #print (op) #testing
        correctAnswer = op(integer1, integer2)
        #print ("correct Answer",correctAnswer)
        opPrint = ""
        if op.func_name == "sub":
            opPrint = "-"
            print (opPrint)
        if op.func_name == "mul":
            opPrint = "*"
            print (opPrint)
        if op.func_name == "add":
            opPrint = "+"
            print (opPrint)
        #print ("What is %s %s %s" ))
        print ("What is " ,integer1, opPrint, integer2)
        answer = int(input("Please enter your answer\n"))
        print ("your answer",answer)
        print ("correct answer",correctAnswer,"\n")
```